# Laravel all output preceded by single character

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

my Laravel application suddenly precedes all (!) output (console, api, web) with a single letter "s".

[image: API output]
[image: Browser]

I guess I accidentally opened some file and saved a missed "cmd+s".

Any ideas where this "s" could be hidden?

Comment: I don't know, maybe look in git to track it down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the S it's hardcoded from a missed cmd+s try in your views folder files

or

before the line where you call your views

Comment: already looked there + can't be the view because even the API endpoint and also the artisan console shows the S preceding every output

Comment: Maybe before some calling request (?)

Comment: Someone suggested that too in the link.. go for a version control next time :D

Comment: yep. I was like "hm I just could do this little side project without any source control. well... now I see how that worked out :P